# How to add scrollable horizontal Linearlayout inside scrollview dynamically

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement an scrollable horizontal Linearlayout inside scrollview in a method dynamically , but the view (LinearLayout) does not scroll!

This method get some result from server and then create the view dynamically. "layout_services" is an vertical LinearLayout which is implemented inside xml file.

Voila the code :

```
 for (ServiceResult serviceResult : response.getResult()) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textViewParams.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);
        textViewParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        textView.setText(serviceResult.getCategory());
        textView.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        if (!serviceResult.getServices().isEmpty()) {
            layout_services.addView(textView);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams scrollLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(getActivity());
            scrollView.setLayoutParams(scrollLayoutParams);
            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            linearLayout.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams horizontalLayoutParams =
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            horizontalLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(horizontalLayoutParams);
            scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
            for (int i = 0; i < serviceResult.getServices().size(); i++) {
                int finalI = i;
                Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
                btn.setText(serviceResult.getServices().get(finalI).getName());
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 200);
                params.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);
                params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                btn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                btn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                });
                linearLayout.addView(btn);
            }
            layout_services.addView(scrollView);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `HorizontalScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` as parent of Linear Layout that you want to scroll horizontally

Comment: always use horizontall scroll view to scroll horizontally

Answer (score 1):

You can try nested scroll view.

Read the documentation here  : [Nested Scroll View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView)